# Chrome extension, store href content, compare with other page href, delete elements on with same href

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I want to parse site for href values. I already did that and can save them in .txt file.
But I need to compare these href values with values of another webpage.
How can I achieve it. The aim is to delete all elements that contain href from my array.
I need it to be stored in some way that user can acces it even after pc reboot, as well this file should be rewriteable. how do I create one.

Here is the code for obtaining href. and it works but how can I use it

```
// Get the content attribute value from the meta tag
var metaElement = document.querySelector('meta[name="itch:path"]');
var contentValue = metaElement ? metaElement.getAttribute('content') : '';

// Extract the content number from the content value
var contentNumber = contentValue.match(/\d+/);

// Use the content number in the download name
var downloadName = contentNumber ? 'href_collection_' + contentNumber[0] + '.txt' : 'href_collection.txt';

// Save the combined href contents to a file (e.g., using Blob and a link)
var blob = new Blob([combinedHrefContents], { type: 'text/plain' });
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
a.download = downloadName;
a.click();
```